# visual studio for Mac solution error

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio for Mac. I tried to create project, but Visual studio project gives error as shown in the picture.

[image]

[image]

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: Firstly, edit your question so people can actually see what on earth you are asking. Secondly, strongly consider if this is even a [valid question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stack overflow. Right now, we have zero clue what you are asking.

Comment: This is an English site, so anything that might be related to localized information (such as the words in your screen shots) should be posted to a local forum of your country instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that I had the same issue. You need to install stable version of .net core sdk: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc4-download.md